# Python Visual Studio os.path.exists fails

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I am having trouble running a Python script in Visual Studio 2017. I am a new Python user and the script I am trying to run was written by someone else.  The script uses `os.path.exists(filename)`, where filename is "dir/filename.txt", and dir is at the same level as the Python script.

When I run the script in the Visual Studio environment, `os.path.exist(filename)` returns false. But when I run it from the command line, everything works fine.

Why doesn't it run in the Visual Studio 2017 environment with "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging"?

Comment: can you show the code which you are trying to use. and also the error.

Comment: not sure about python, but for other VS projects can have a `Working directory` set to other path than the default one.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, setting the working directory solved the problem

Comment: @user1522446 good that it helped, too bad that I didn't post that as an answer ;)